# Un-upvote followed by re-upvote = -10 reputation bug

Tags: bug, reputation, voting

In the last two days I received two un-upvotes immediately followed by a "re-upvote". To me this means that the user experimented with the voting system, thinking that they could add another upvote after my answer was updated. The [timelines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5764/werner?tab=reputation) also reflect this suspicion:

### Yesterday:

[image]

### Today:

[image]

However, the reputation tally for both these days are short by the "un-upvote count" of 10. Yesterday I should have received 260 reputation, and today 230. Yet, yesterday I (only) received 250 and today 220. Why does an "un-upvote" followed by a re-upvote count as -10 reputation rather than 0?

---

This is clearly a bug, since a [reputation recalc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation) reveals the appropriate daily reputation:

```
 2     58215 (10)
 2     58588 (10)
 2     55513 (10)
 2     58588 (10)
 2     27475 (5)
 2     59084 (10)
 2     59084 (10)
 2     59092 (10)
 2     59092 (10)
 2     59084 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 1     59084 (15)
 1     59094 (15)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     34319 (10)
 2     59092 (10)
 2     59084 (10)
 2     59092 (10)
 1     59092 [15]
 2     59094 [5]
 2     59084 [0]
 2     55513 [0]
 2     59123 [0]
 2     59123 [0]
 2     59123 [0]
 2     31704 [0]
 2     59123 [0]
 1     59123 [15]
 2     59123 [0]
-- 2012-06-08 rep +260  = 61742     
 2     59138 (10)
 2     59123 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     59138 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     56630 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     59148 (10)
 2     59094 (10)
 2     59123 (10)
 2     59138 (10)
 2     45865 (10)
 2     59138 (10)
 1     59138 (15)
 2     39701 (10)
 2     59138 (10)
 2     59204 (10)
 2     59204 (10)
 2     59148 [10]
 2     59204 [0]
 2     58588 [0]
 2     59204 [0]
 2     59204 [0]
 2     59260 [0]
 1     59260 [15]
 2     59260 [0]
-- 2012-06-09 rep +230  = 61972
```